# Can I plug my SD card from Pi 4 into a Pi 3?

Tags: pi-3, pi-4

Can I use my SD card from a Raspberry Pi 4 2GB in Raspberry Pi 3? If not, is there a way to get some python and node-red files from my SD card as my Raspberry Pi 4 kinda got fried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use an sd card from a Pi4 in a Pi3.

The only issue might be if you have put any Pi4 specific settings in the general section of /boot/config.txt.

Comment: It works! All the files are there.Thank you so much. You're a lifesaver